# What is the meaning of "the opposition of the pocket is best met through the pocket"

Tags: proverbs

I'm writing a book on Adam Smith and I would like to clarify what is the meaning of the sentence below:

"But his advice implies that he agreed with the political maxim that the opposition of the pocket is best met through the pocket."

It is found at part XXIII.26 of http://www.econlib.org/library/YPDBooks/Rae/raeLS23.html

Comment: Never heard it.  My best guess, especially given that the subject is Adam Smith, is that objections on the basis of cost are best met by arguing that money will be saved, such as arguing that education is expensive but ignorance is more so.

Comment: Smith's original language is very roundabout, so it's hard to interpret.  Perhaps something like **you have to spend money to make money** or **throw some money at the problem.** _...it may be done at little expense and with no great trouble. I could even point to some persons who, I think, are fit and likely to deal with them successfully for this purpose."_

Comment: The author of a book about Adam Smith is commenting on what Smith means in a letter (quoted by Yosef Baskin above).  The quotation as I read it says that those who object to a policy because it will hurt their financial situation (pocket) should be dealt with financially.  (I don't think he's right about what Smith meant, but that's what he says.)

Comment: So it says one should bribe to get a policy approved?

Comment: Not sure where you got the bribing idea. It seems to mean addressing the financial argument by some financial means. If I argue that a new bill will make me poor, show me that my profits will increase directly in some other way due to the bill. Answer money lost with money gained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merriam-Webster's definition number 2 of [pocket](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pocket) is

> supply of money.

"The opposition of the pocket" is a metaphor for opposition on financial grounds. In the instance cited some of the manufacturers in Great Britain were concerned that free trade between Ireland and Great Britain would undermine their position, because Irish manufacturers could produce things more cheaply.

"Is best met through the pocket" is saying that the best way to meet the opposition, to overcome it, is also financial.

The maxim says that the best way to "buy off" those who oppose a policy for financial reasons is by providing a financial solution. In itself the maxim does not necessarily endorse bribery. Opposition from groups which will be adversely affected by a proposed public policy may be mollified by compensation and/or the provision of new opportunities. Similarly today, opposition to a policy on environmental grounds might be mollified by landscaping or carbon offsetting.

In the particular context the reference to the principal men, and the reluctance to give details, suggest bribing the leading manufacturers, rather than producing a solution to mitigate the effects on all manufacturers (and workers) may have been intended.

Smith was advising the government on trade negotiations between Great Britain and Ireland. 237 years later, negotiations are about to commence between the EU27 (Republic of Ireland and the European Continent) on the one hand, and the UK (Northern Ireland and Great Britain) on the other. How far Smith's counsels are followed remains to be seen.